# Tree with six or more children

Tags: trees, qtree

I'm using `qtree` and a tree with five children works perfectly:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree[.n 1 2 3 4 5 ]

\end{document}
```

[image: Tree with 5 children]

But when I add another node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree[.n 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]

\end{document}
```

It prints a single `6`. Checking the [package documentation](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/qtree/qtreenotes.pdf) (warning: pdf) there seems to be a constraint of 5 children per node, and the reason eludes me.

What is the correct way to build such a tree?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Are you tied to `qtree` or can you consider an alternative?

Comment: The reason for the restriction is basically that subtrees are built individually (i.e. there is code for 2, 3, 4, and 5 branching trees) rather than with an iterative or recursive algorithm.  So the 5 branch limit is a hard limit.  Given that linguistics trees (for which the package was developed) rarely, if ever require more branching than that, the hard limit is not a practical problem for linguists.

Comment: @AlanMunn I should have remembered that since I hacked the 1- and 2- branch cases to support incremental visibility with `beamer`. (If a logician had written the package, it probably wouldn't have as many as 5!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not object to using `tikz`, you have a number of more flexible options. `tikz` has a `trees` library but you will probably prefer something with a brackets-type syntax. `tikz-qtree` is one option. `forest` is another.

## `tikz-qtree`

This option lets you keep using just the same syntax as `qtree`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree
  [.n 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>tikz-qtree</code> tree with 6 children]

## `forest`

This option requires you to use a different syntax but it should nonetheless be rather familiar in many respects. The pay-off comes in the form of greater power and flexibility. While that's not needed for this example, it would be worth switching if you have more demanding trees to draw.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  [n
    [1]
    [2]
    [3]
    [4]
    [5]
    [6]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>forest</code> tree with 6 children]

Or perhaps:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
  }
  [n
  [1]
  [3]
  [3]
  [4]
  [5]
  [6]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: Another <code>forest</code> tree with 6 children]

Comment: Great answer. I ended up using `tikz-qtree` as a drop-in replacement. The only feature missing is the automatic centering, but I can live with that.